# Migrate project to gradle file??This project does not use Gradle build system.We recommend that you migrate to using Gradle build system

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Am not getting *gradle file in the Android project* as it is unavailable in android studio bt is available in project file folder. I tried a lot to resolve this issue but I failed.

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score 0):

The project thinks it's still a non-Gradle based project; it's not the presence of the build.gradle file that makes it Gradle-based, but it's how the project was set up in the first place. You'll need to re-import your project to finish the conversion to Gradle.

First, though, it looks like you don't have a settings.gradle file; it looks like you need one. Since you've set up your project as a single-module project, then you can put the file in your project's root directory, next to build.gradle. It should contain this:

```
import ':'
```

In the future if you add more modules to your project you may want to convert it to a multi-module directory structure, but you don't need to worry about that now. In any event, now you need to do the re-import in Android Studio:

Close your project
Back up your project
Delete the .idea folder in the root directory of the project
Delete all the .iml files in your project
Import your project in Android Studio, and in the dialog that prompts you for a file, choose the build.gradle file.
After this, you should be good to go.

Comment: It wont worked for me...need another method to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have facing an exact same situation in past, I solved this error by following step

**First of all I would remove following files/directories from your project-folder:**

- bin/
- build/
- .idea/
- .gradle/
- projectname.iml

**when you open android studio import your project**

Comment: It wont worked for me...need another method to solve the issue

Comment: Is this project clone from `GitHub`?

Comment: Yes..its a bitbucket project

Comment: Is it okay to share your project link?

Comment: okay, no problem. when you open android studio which option you select `Open an existing android studio project` or `import project`

Comment: When i choose existing option , after cloning my project no gradle file is present...When i choose import project it asked me to give the gradle location...that was confusing ...bocoz the location i share to that shows always incorrect